# Шаблонизатор на C

Tags: c, шаблонизаторы

Есть файл profile.page(шаблон) в котором нужно заменить подстроки вида "%sometext%"(сейчас там есть %FIO%, %AGE%, %INFO%) на соответствующие данные из структуры из файла *.dat и все это выводить в браузере. Все это на С. Не понимаю как написать функцию которая считывает данные из шаблона и находит нужные подстроки. Объясните пожалуйста как это сделать.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[50];
    char fathername[50];
    char surname[50];
    char info[1500];
    long int birthday;
    char userpic[50];
    char address[20];
} STUDENT;

typedef struct {
    char* key;
    char* value;
} MATHING;

int find(char *str, char *p) {
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str)-strlen(p); i++) {
        char f = 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < strlen(p); j++) {
            if(str[i+j]!=p[j]) {
                f = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(f && str[i+strlen(p)]=='=')
            return i+1+strlen(p);
    }
    return -1;
}

char * get_param(char *str, char *s) {
    int i = find(str, s);
    if(i<0)
        return NULL;
    char * r = malloc(strlen(str)-i);
    for(int k = i; k < strlen(str); k++) {
        if(str[k]=='&' || &str[k]==0) {
            r[k-i] = 0;
            break;
        }
        r[k-i] = str[k];
    }
    return r;
}

/* Заменяет *tmpl на *change в строке *s */
char * replace(char *s, char *tmpl, char *change) {
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(s));
    char *p;
    if(!(p = strstr(s, tmpl)))
        return s;
    strncpy(buf, s, p-s);
    buf[p-s] = '\0';
    sprintf(buf+(p-s), "%s%s", change, p+strlen(tmpl));
    return buf;
}

/* Возвращает строку типа "%sometext%" или NULL(если нет такой строки) из *ff */
char * find_tmpl(char *ff) {
    char* text;
    char* vspom;
    int t = 0;
    while(*ff) //бежим по тексту в поиске <%>
    {
        if(*ff == '%')
        {
            vspom = ff;
            while(*vspom != '%') //вычисляем длинну строки между <%>
            {
                t++;
                *vspom++;
            }
            text = malloc(sizeof(char) * t + 1);

            int g = 0;
            while(*ff != '%') //записываем строку заключенную между <%>
            {
                text[g] = *ff++;
                g++;
            }
            text[g+1] = '\0';
            return text;
        }
        *ff++;
    }
    return NULL;
}


char * open_file(char *fn, struct profile p) {
    char* dir = "/var/www/eben/pages/";
    char* end = ".page";
    char* fileName = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(dir) + strlen(end) + strlen(fn)));
    strcat(fileName, dir);
    strcat(fileName, fn);
    strcat(fileName, end);

    char* ff;
    FILE* fp;
    if((fp = fopen(fileName, "r")) != NULL) {
        while(!feof(fp)) {
            char* tmp = fgets(fp);
            /* считывание данных из шаблонного файла */
        }
    fclose(fp);
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    /*char *file_struct = "/var/www/eben/data/";
    char *param = get_param(argv[1], "user");
    file_struct = strcat(file_struct, param);
    file_struct = strcat(file_struct, ".dat");
    / TODO: Считывание структуры */

    STUDENT s1 = {
        "name",
        "surname",
        "fathername",
        "asdljfnlskndflnsldnflskdnflksndf",
        425001600,
        "asasasasasasasas",
        "qwqwqwqwqwqwqwqqw"
    };

    MATCHING *m;

    printf("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=us-ascii\n\n");    
    printf("%s", (open_file("profile", s1)));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Не понимаю как написать функцию которая считывает данные из шаблона и
>   находит нужные подстроки.

Как читать строки из файла, я уж рассказывать не буду, а по поводу поиска :

```
$ man 3 strstr
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);

DESCRIPTION
       The  strstr()  function finds the first occurrence of the 
substring needle in the string haystack.
```

и замены :

У Вас должен быть буфер строки для обработки, например

```
char wrk[1024];
```

Основной цикл работы программы:

1. Считываете исходную строку во входной буфер
2. Проверяете, что во входном буфере нет ничего для замены

   3.1. Если и вправду, ничего нет - копируете входной буфер в выходной.

   3.2. Иначе - выполняем замену

   3.2.1. В wrk копируете начало строки ДО заменяемого текста (strncpy)

   3.2.2. В wrk дописываете заменяющий текст (strncat)

   3.2.3. В wrk дописываете остаток входного буфера ПОСЛЕ заменяемого текста (strcat)
   3.2.4. Копируете wrk в выходной буфер
3. Пишите выходной буфер в файл.